# How do I generate nested DOM elements based on an AJAX result in Angular?

Tags: html, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I'm new to Angular so be gentle with me! I'm looking at rendering subsection DOM elements based on an AJAX response, how do I go about implementing the below in Angular?

On page load a list of section headers is returned from the controller:

[image: Section Headers, returned by default]

Clicking on any of these sections (red) would show a subsection list (blue), each of these blue headers can be clicked to show another list (black), bearing in mind I only want to show the immediate-child sections for each section/subsection/sub-subsection header click:

[image: Expanded View]

I've got the template code I want to use for each of these, but how do I go about bringing these templates together?

So far from looking around I get the impression I should be creating a directive for the section, sub-section and sub-sub-section (yes?), can I then bind a template to the result of an HTTP Service call? I.e expanding as the detail screenshot above:

```
<div area="PSED">
    Personal, Social and Emotional Development
    <div aspect="MH">
        Making Relationships
        <div goal="BLAH">
            <input type="checkbox"> Blah, Blah, Blah
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was hoping to reduce page load time by returning as little data as necessary and populating sections as-required by the user.

I hope this is a reasonable question as I couldn't find anything demonstrating what I need (perhaps my ignorance of ng was causing me to omit an important keyword from my searches).

Thanks in advance for any advice provided.

Andy

Comment: So, on each section click, you want to make a call to a backend server to return a list of sub (and sub-sub) sections? Will the server be returning HTML, or a JSON containing the sections? There are endless ways to do what (I think) you want to achieve, but it seems like you'd be better off loading the entire section list at once, and using the `ng-hide`, `ng-show`, and `ng-if` directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are trying to dynamically add nodes to a  tree-like structure after an ajax call. You can use a combination of ng-include and a recursive template to do this. Here's a rough example that doesn't include the logic for collapsing nodes but I think it gets the idea across.

View:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
     <span ng-click="add(data)">{{data.name}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", function($scope, $http) {     
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;

        //make your call here and set your child node data
        //$http.get('...').then(function(res){
        //   data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: res.data});
        //});

        //test data
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});

    };
    $scope.tree = [{name: "Top Node", nodes: []}];
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfreeze/c9mrhxf2/1/

Comment: Thanks for the working example, I should be able to work something out now using this pattern; this was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for - I think I was too caught up in all the unfamiliar functionality. Cheers dude!